# A regex for range of numbers in curl

Tags: regex, linux, range

I am looking to download a series of png files from a website with curl. They are numbered from b0000.png through b0373.png. Keep getting error message "no matches found".

`b0+\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\b.png` is what I think it might be for pages b0000 through b0100, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In your pattern `b0+\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\b.png` the `\b` in this part `0+\b` is not going to work because there is no word boundary between a 0 and another digit coming from the following alternation.

You could also omit the word boundary in this part `\b.png` and escape the dot to match it literally.

If you want to match only zeroes, you can make the part from 1-100 optional as for now there is at least a value from the alternation expected.

The alternation could be shortened making the 0-9 part optional `[1-9][0-9]?`

---

To match from `b0000.png` to `b0100.png` you could update the pattern to:

```
b0+(100|[1-9][0-9]?)?\.png
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1nTIS/1)

The whole range from 0000 to 0373 can be matched using:

```
b0+([1-9][0-9]?|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-6][0-9]|37[0-3])?\.png
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFuts5/1)

Comment: I think I completely misread the question. Thought OP needed range 0000-0373. This makes more sense =)

Comment: @JvdV Not sure if you misread the question :) I only focused on the pattern the OP tried, not sure if the whole range should be matched though..

Comment: Btw, just noticed this would match `b0.png`. Not sure if it would be a significant problem though.

Comment: @JvdV I think we have to wait to get some clarification on that from the OP

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me (if lookbehinds are supported in curl?):

---

**1)** For a range `0000-0100`:

```
b0(0\d\d|100)\.png
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DIbhJzAcvOaiHYNm)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AWu33V/2)

---

**2)** For a range `0000-0373`:

```
b0[0-3]((?<=[0-2])\d|(?<=3)[0-7])((?<=37)[0-3]|(?<!37)\d)\.png
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2H9E9DZVWjp4doHF)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AWu33V/1)

Use non-capture groups for a full match if you rather do that:

```
b0[0-3](?:(?<=[0-2])\d|(?<=3)[0-7])(?:(?<=37)[0-3]|(?<!37)\d)\.png
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned curl, perhaps you don't need a regexp.
You could be fine with something like:

```
for i in {0000..0373}; do curl http://example.org/b$i.png -O; done
```

PS: The braces expansion requires you to run the command from zsh and not bash.